# Cannot heroku run rake db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm having issues with my app.

I am trying to run:

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

but I get this error:

```
Running rake db:migrate on pierwsza1... up, run.7908
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (22.9ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Migrating to AddUserIdToPins (20160515200705)
   (1.9ms)  BEGIN
== 20160515200705 AddUserIdToPins: migrating ==================================
-- add_column(:pins, :user_id, :integrer)
   (3.6ms)  ALTER TABLE "pins" ADD "user_id" integrer
   (8.6ms)  ROLLBACK
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:
PG::UndefinedObject: ERROR:  type "integrer" does not exist
LINE 1: ALTER TABLE "pins" ADD "user_id" integrer
```

These are the contents of the file I generated with the `rails generate migration add_user_id_to_pins user_id:integer:index:`

```
class AddUserIdToPins < ActiveRecord::Migration  
   def change  
    add_column :pins, :user_id, :integer  
    add_index :pins, :user_id  
  end  
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In your migration file you have defined `user_id` as an integ**r**er instead of an `integer`

You've just need to update your migration file with a valid type

Answer (score 0):

Check this line of your logs :

```
PG::UndefinedObject: ERROR:  type "integrer" does not exist
LINE 1: ALTER TABLE "pins" ADD "user_id" integrer
```

It clearly states that you have mistyped "integer" with "integrer". Please correct that in your file.